# Getting exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Getting the following exception , while implementing Jwt Spring Security implementation :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl .

in a Spring Boot project

The dependencies in pom.xml are as following :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The detailed bootstrap is as following :

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl
] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(Unknown Source)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:99)
    at com.mpcz.services.jwt.security.JwtTokenUtil.generateToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:92)
    at com.mpcz.services.jwt.security.JwtTokenUtil.generateToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:85)
    at com.mpcz.services.controller.ConsumerLoginController.register(ConsumerLoginController.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Getting the above mentioned error while generating JWT token at  below mentioned code :

```
Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setExpiration(generateExpirationDate()).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
```

Comment: I found solution for the above problem : Add the following in pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Also downloaded Xercesxml 2.12.0 version and added to pom.xml

Comment: You should add a clean response and accept it. This is the only place I found this (perfectly working) solution, thank you.

Comment: @Giggs thank you for solution !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75691813/12349305 Answer if you use springboot 3

Answer (score 30):

For future reference, the solution was adding the following dependency in order to avoid the java 11 issue:

For Maven projects:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For gradle projects:

```
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1'
```

Credits to @Giggs

Answer (score 6):

Adding JAXB API dependency solved my issue.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this dependency to the pom file worked for me :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

That also worked just fine for me while using OpenJDK 11. w/o any code modification.

I am using java.base.* enc/dec on my fronted class instead of javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, but jjwt (0.9.0) brings it back in when generating the token.

your solution is good, did not have to add the Xercesxml to my pom.xml, probably because I was only doing basic jwt.

Regards,

Dezman!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For me adding javax api dependency fixed my bug.

```
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1'
```

Thanks @Andrei